# PHP cookie returning "deleted" as value

Tags: php, cookies

This is a really odd issue I'm having, and I'm having a hard time figuring out what's going on. Once in awhile, my cookie returns the value "deleted" instead of its proper value. Do any web browsers turn the cookie value to "deleted" if it has expired?

I've done a ton of Google searches and SO searches, and can't find anything like this.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to ensure that when you call `setcookie()` you are setting a reasonable expiry time that will ensure that your cookie will not expire while being used.

[From the php documentation (trimmed for important parts):](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

> The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number
>   of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set
>   this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you
>   want it to expire.
>
> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the
>   session (when the browser closes).

**EDIT**

further down the `setcookie()` documentation I found this

> Cookies must be deleted with the same parameters as they were set
>   with. If the value argument is an empty string, or FALSE, and all
>   other arguments match a previous call to setcookie, then the cookie
>   with the specified name will be deleted from the remote client. This
>   is internally achieved by setting value to 'deleted' and expiration
>   time to one year in past.

i.e. it seems that your cookie is somewhere being updated to either an empty string or being set to false.

Comment: I've set it as a year. I don't think that's the issue. It's actually returning that the value is "deleted".

Comment: You should post the code that sets your cookies. Any cookie set with a `false` value or empty string would be deleted. PHP deletes cookies by "setting value to 'deleted' and expiration time to one year in past." This is also coming from the PHP `setcookie()` documentation.

Comment: See my edit as I found more information prudent to your issue.

Comment: @DamonSwayn This sounds like exactly the issue. I'm going to log when my cookies are set, and see if the value is ever set as empty. I will report back with my findings!

Comment: You can see it [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/head.c#L134) in the php source.